# Python - How to Set Custom Fields using NetSuite webservices

Tags: python, netsuite, zeep

I'm trying to be able to set a custom fields in NetSuite using webservices. 
The WSDL I'm using is: https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2017_2_0/netsuite.wsdl

Currently I'm testing it on creating a customer. Here's what I have so far:

```
def add_customer():
  client = login_client()
  RecordRef = client.get_type('ns0:RecordRef')
  Customer = client.get_type('ns13:Customer')
  customer = Customer(
    companyName='TEST',
    subsidiary = RecordRef(internalId='5', type='subsidiary')
  )
  response = client.service.add(customer)
  print(response) 

add_customer()
```

This Works perfectly, but now I'm trying to set a custom field with id `custfield1`
After doing some searching, I found:

http://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/schema/other/customfieldlist.html?mode=package

From this link I know that I'll be needing to use `CustomFieldRef`, I'm just not sure how it would be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

```
def add_customer():
   client = login_client()
   RecordRef = client.get_type('ns0:RecordRef')
   StringCustomFieldRef = client.get_type('ns0:StringCustomFieldRef') #StringCustomFieldRef
   CustomFieldList = client.get_type('ns0:CustomFieldList') #To go from object to list

   #Cust field 1
   acctName = StringCustomFieldRef()
   acctName.internalID = '1569'
   acctName.scriptId = 'custentity_account_name'
   acctName.value = 'testData'

   #custField2
   acctID= StringCustomFieldRef()
   acctID.internalId= '1596'
   acctID.scriptId= 'custentity_sf_account_id'
   acctID.value = 'FIELD DATA'

   Customer = client.get_type('ns13:Customer')
   customer = Customer(
      companyName='TEST',
      entityId='TEST ID',
      subsidiary = RecordRef(internalId='5', type='subsidiary'),
      customFieldList = CustomFieldList([acctID,acctName]) #List of cust objects
   )
   response = client.service.add(customer)
   print(response)

add_customer()
```

You have to use the Ref type for the field you are working with: https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_n3458179.html